# how to keyframe "animated" of rigid bodies to multiple objects

Tags: python, animation, physics, keyframes

Is there any "trick" to how I can set keyframes for "animated" for a rigid body for multiple objects?

I know, "normally" you can select multiple objects and set press "I" -> location and it works. Unfortunately not for animated.

I cannot use "link animation data" because they are all at different locations and of course, I don't want them to be at the same location.

my scene looks like this:

[image]

so i have a lot of balls "animated" so that they get a starting speed in y-direction. Then i set animated off so that rigid body simulation starts. Then the react with the springs on the ground.

[image]

Comment: Uh... What do you mean? You could just press `I` while hovering over the animated checkbox?

Comment: nope, it just sets the keyframe for ONE object, not for multiple

Comment: So why not just select those objects and link animation data?

Comment: because they are at different locations, but i don't want them to be on the same location

Comment: Maybe parent your objects to an empty? Then you can link the animation data

Comment: @moonboots : I am not sure how I could do that? Won’t it copy the location animation data as well?

Comment: sure it won't work if you've keyframed the location of the first object, but could you please show exactly the whole scene and animation you're trying to achieve?

Comment: maybe this is python work...

Comment: so instead of animating the balls at the beginning, why not parenting all to an empty and then animate the empty only? For the balls you only need to create an action that will be Animated on and off?

Comment: great, works, thank you! wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of animating the balls at the beginning, parent them all to an empty then animate the empty only. For the balls, you only need to create an action that will be the *Animated* option on and off: Do it for one ball, select all the other balls, make the first one active, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Animation Data*.